# Proper use of std::unique_ptr release() for raw pointer function argument

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, unique-ptr

I'm adding a child element to a parent element. The parent's `addChildElement()` takes a raw pointer (and belongs to a library that I can't change), then assumes ownership and deletes.

```
std::unique_ptr<Element> child {new Element};

// ...do things...

parent.addChildElement (child.release()); // will be deleted by parent
```

Is this correct modern practice? To use a unique_ptr until the last possible moment, rather than a raw pointer?

Comment: Yes, it is. The unique pointer releases the ownership of the pointed data once `release` is called.

Comment: Modern practices are modern so still under debates ^^ In the particular case you're showing, it looks like a good use of pointers to me

Comment: What is `addChildElement`? Maybe it is better to use signature `void addChildElelement(std::unique_ptr<Element> &&)` not to use `release` function.

Comment: @ilotXXI "belongs to a library that I can't change"

Comment: @ilotXXI If you can change signature (which is not possible in this case) I would still think that taking the `unique_ptr` instance by value instead of r-value reference is the best way to solve the problem, since you want to take ownership.